# How to make python interactive console based on blocks rather than lines

Tags: command-line, python

I want my python interactive console in terminal to work like the one in pycharm or something like jupyter notebook but I can't find how.

For example when I do:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print('Make it work nice')
...
>>>
```

And then I press up arrow I want to see something like this:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print('Make it work nice')
...
```

Where I can edit both lines. but I get only this:

```
>>>     print('Make it work nice')
```

So is it possible to make it work as I want and if not is there any extremely lightweight tool(something smaller than an IDE or Browser. something as heavy as VIM for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IPython](https://ipython.org) is the shell in Jupyter. You can install it with pip:

```
sudo pip3 install ipython
```

Note that IPython is also available in the Ubuntu repos, but it's a much older version.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ptpython](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/ptpython). It's not in the repositories but you can easily install it via `pip3`.